# Не запускается Create React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, install

Инсталляция с помощью `npm` для macOS (+Node.JS):

```
bash command not found
```

Какие варианты?
Логи установки могу выложить.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема побеждена, проштудировав все логи поняла, что не было доступа как админ (root), использовав sudo перед установкой все запустилось.